# Error while uploading archive to iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, archive, iphone-developer-program

'Your account already has a valid iOS distribution certificate'. I get this error every time I try to upload my archive. I don't have two dev accounts, nor did I use another mac before. Please help

Comment: Did you have the right Private and Public Key for your distribution in your laptop? Make sure you match them up with the one in the Provisioning Profile. Maybe you create more than 1 distribution. check the date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Your account already has a valid certificate**

This dialog appears if the **certificate already exists** in Member Center.

Typically, this happens when you move from one Mac to another. If possible, export your certificates as a developer profile file on the other Mac, and then import them on your new Mac.

Have a look into **Troubleshooting** section of [App Distribution Guide.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Troubleshooting/Troubleshooting.html) It is described there how to solve this error.

Comment: I'm don't have a distribution certificate because i'm not the "Team Agent" of the account i'm using. I can't generate a distribution certificate without being the "Team Agent", neither generate another distribution certificate as "Admin" (that my role now). How do i fix this? Can i validate/export a build without a distribution certificate?

Answer (score 8):

This is a problem that appears after the updating to xCode 6. Just rename your provisioning profile in the developer portal, and then refresh the account info in xCode. Voila :-)

Comment: Thanks you for that one! I was not in the mood for requesting new certificates etc. I did not even rename, just asked to edit and then generate.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this error after Updating Xcode 6, to fix it

- Revoke the IOS Distribution Certificate (from Member Centre ==> Certificates ==> Production).
- Open Xcode project and re-login again to your account.
- in the Account screen, click "View Details"
- in the bottom left click the refresh button.

This will re-create the certificate automatically. and everything will work again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solution was to request a new dist cert, install it in my key chain, and also recreate the dist prov profile. Apparently, the cert I had in my keychain was old and was revoked and downloading the new cert from the dev center was not enough as it does not include private keys.